# Draggable events using "on" syntax

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I have a draggable like this:

```
handle.draggable(start: function(event, args){ ... });
```

what's the equivalent of it for using with `on`?

```
handle.on("dragStart", function(){ ... });
```

I have a generic logic for `mousedown/dragStart` and `mouseup/dragStop`, so I'd like to use it like:

```
handle.on("mousedown dragStart", function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 'dragstart' and 'dragstop'. For complete list of event names, visit [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)